# Help needed with moon area function problem

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I am having trouble with a question that involves a function that calculates the area of the moon in terms of time, given the appearance of the moon at different stages. I have attempted to solve the problem but I am not sure if I am on the right track. I would appreciate any help or guidance.

The question is as follows:

> From Earth, the moon can be seen in different states. This function provides a graph of what the crescent looks like until it is no longer visible. You can use the function to calculate the moon in "area units" in terms of $A(t)$ where $t$ is the time in days after the crescent is visible.
>
> 1. Determine $A(3)$.
> 2. Determine $A'(3)$.
>
> $$
> f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1+\tan\left(\frac{2\pi}{29.5}t\right)}}
> $$

My attempt at solving the problem involves substituting $t = 3$ into the function to find $A(3)$. However, I am unsure of how to find $A'(3)$. I would appreciate any guidance or tips on how to

Comment: What is $A$? Are you familiar with the chain rule?  Do you mean $\tan\left(\frac{2\pi}{29.5}\right)t$, or $\tan\left(\frac{2\pi}{29.5}t\right)$?

Comment: I think $f$ is a curve which bounds the shape, not the shape's area. So $A$ is the area of the shape between the graph of $f$ and a semicircle, which can be found using an integral.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thank you for your response and for seeking clarification on my question.

 is the area of the moon at a given time t in days after the appearance of the half-moon. The function f(x) is used to calculate the area of the moon in "area units" with respect to time, A(t).

Yes, I am familiar with the chain rule.

Regarding the second part of your question, I apologize for the confusion. The correct expression should be tan((2/29.5)), indicating that 2/29.5 is multiplied by t and then passed as an argument to the tangent function.

Comment: I still have no idea what $A$ is.  How does it relate to $f$?  Also, never be afraid to use parentheses.  They are great for disambiguating.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$A(t)=\int_{-1}^1f(x,t)\,dx$$
It follows by DUIS (differentiating under integral sign) that
$$A'(t)=\int_{-1}^1f_t(x,t)\,dx$$
where $f_t$ is the partial derivative with respect to $t$. Here
$$f_t(x,t)=-\frac12\sqrt{1-x^2}\left(1+\tan\frac{2\pi t}{29.95}\right)^{-3/2}\left(\sec^2\frac{2\pi t}{29.95}\right)\frac{2\pi}{29.95}$$
Despite the complexity this is just some function of only $t$ multiplied by $\sqrt{1-x^2}$, which means we can simply substitute this derivative and then $t=3$ into the integral for $A'(t)$ above and find $A'(3)=-0.110981\dots$

Comment: You seem to assume that $A$ is the area under $f$.  I don't think it is clear from the question that this is the case.  aschepler, in a comment, posits that $A$ is the area *between* $f$ and the unit semicircle above the $x$-axis.  In such cases, where there is ambiguity, I think it is best to wait for the original asker to clarify the question before posting an answer.